# CCNET Server Exception

Tags: ccnet-config

CCNET is throwing this exeption on the web dashboard. What is causing this?
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:21234 Server stack trace: at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress) at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP) at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.RemoteConnection.CreateNewSocket(EndPoint ipEndPoint) at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.RemoteConnection.CreateNewSocket() at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.RemoteConnection.GetSocket() at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.SocketCache.GetSocket(String machinePortAndSid, Boolean openNew) at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpClientTransportSink.SendRequestWithRetry(IMessage msg, ITransportHeaders requestHeaders, Stream requestStream) at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpClientTransportSink.ProcessMessage(IMessage msg, ITransportHeaders requestHeaders, Stream requestStream, ITransportHeaders& responseHeaders, Stream& responseStream) at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.BinaryClientFormatterSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg) Exception rethrown at [0]: at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Remote.ICruiseManager.GetServerLog() at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.WebDashboard.ServerConnection.ServerAggregatingCruiseManagerWrapper.GetServerLog(IServerSpecifier serverSpecifier) at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.WebDashboard.Plugins.ServerReport.ServerLogServerPlugin.Execute(ICruiseRequest request) at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.WebDashboard.MVC.Cruise.ServerCheckingProxyAction.Execute(ICruiseRequest cruiseRequest) at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.WebDashboard.MVC.Cruise.CruiseActionProxyAction.Execute(IRequest request) at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.WebDashboard.MVC.Cruise.ExceptionCatchingActionProxy.Execute(IRequest request)

Answer (score 17):

have you checked the ccservice is started? you can use telnet to check this, and, for testing, we can use ccnet.exe which is an console app for simplified

Answer (score 5):

This issue looks like another process locks the same port that CCNet is using. You can use [PortMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644) to track which process is locking that specific port. You can also configure CCNet in the config file to use a different port to avoid collision. The configuration should look as follow

```
 <system.runtime.remoting> 
    <application> 
      <channels> 
          <!-- change port here -->
          <channel ref="tcp" port="21234">              
          <serverProviders> 
            <formatter ref="binary" typeFilterLevel="Full"/> 
          </serverProviders> 
        </channel> 
      </channels> 
    </application> 
  </system.runtime.remoting>
```